# Не получается изменить форму Toolbar (ActionBar) Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toolbar

Добрый день!
Ищу способ изменить форму верхнего Toolbar (ActionBar), как на этом скрине.
Использую API 21. Обратите внимание под toolbar-ом на скрине есть цветная тень (но можно ограничиться и стандартной не цветной). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Были мысли попробовать через SVG. Может быть есть какие-то решения, чтобы сделать этот скругленный тулбар?
Заранее благодарю всех небезразличных.

Comment: вы можете просто нарисовать такой бэкграунд - прямугольник, у которого верхняя часть синяя, нижняя  - белая. Там же нарисовать любую тень.

Comment: А как в таком случае контент будет заезжать под тулбар? По замыслу там будет карта Google Maps

Comment: тогда низ сделайте не белый, а прозрачный

Answer (score 4):

Я бы попробовал 2 варианта:

1) Классический тулбар, в котором задается фоновый `drawable` заданный через xml, типа:

```
<shape android:shape="oval"/>
```

2) Попробовал бы применить [ArcLayout](https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это уже интереснее. Спасибо буду читать.